# Referencing in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have 2 for loops in order to get 2 different pieces of information from a different excel.  The first for loops works fine there is no problems with it. I want the second for loop to use as a source a cell that is in a different excel (the first for loop uses the current workbook as a source cell). The problem is the name of the excel changes as shown in the path (`Scorecard " & JobNumber & ".xlsm'`). Do I need to create new variables and define that variable as the path to the new excel? Or is there a better way to make this work? Basically it should take a piece of information in a specific cell and populate it on another excel (the master excel).

```
Sub Narrative()

Dim JobNumber As String
Dim srcCell As String

Dim id As Integer

For id = 4 To 150
    srcCell = "C" & id

    JobNumber = Range(srcCell).Value

    Range("P" & id).Value = "=IFERROR('Y:\Public\QA Other\Scorecards\Scorecard " & JobNumber & ".xlsm'!TotalN, "" "")"
Next

For id = 4 To 150
    srcCell = "S" & id

    JobNumber = Range(srcCell).Value

    Range("R" & id).Value = "=IFERROR('Y:\Public\QA Other\Scorecards\Scorecard " & JobNumber & ".xlsm'!Analyst, "" "")"
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: In order to resolve this I think you need to tell us (a) whether the "different excel" workbook is open when running the macro (b) what the workbook name of the "different excel" is, and what sheet name you want to reference in it in order to determine the job number which you are using to create the name of the workbook in the second formula.

Comment: The different excel is not open when I run the macro but I am pretty sure the macro opens the excel in the background. What I have is a master excel in the same folder there are new excel documents being created everyday with the name Scorecard + JobNumber. In this case JobNumber changes per document. What I currently do is add the job numbers to my master and then run the excel so it takes the ones in the "C" column of my master excel to populate numbers in another column of the same master excel. .

Comment: In the second loop I am trying to get information from a cell in the excels being created to populate in the master excel. I have 5 macros that I run per sheet of the different excel documents. So I need that information in that cell of each sheet to populate in my master excel since it the information in that cell (Analyst) changes per document being created per sheet.

Comment: So you have a list of job numbers in column C of one workbook.  Do you also have another list of job numbers in column S of ... the same workbook? Another workbook?  Every single workbook?  I'm beginning to think that you don't need two loops at all - that everything between the `Range("P" & id).Value = ...` and the `Range("R" & id).Value = ...` statements should just be deleted.  (And those two statements should really be using the `.Formula` property, not the `.Value` property, but that won't usually cause any issues other than efficiency ones.)

Comment: So you want the "R4" cell address to be updated with information from the Analyst sheet of workbooks incrementally named Scorecard + JobNumber? I still don't understand what you are trying to accomplish with your IFERROR function...

Comment: @user2731076 - I think `TotalN` and `Analyst` are named ranges with workbook scope, not worksheets.  (If they were worksheets the formula wouldn't make sense.)  And the `IFERROR` will just return a space if the range name doesn't exist.

Comment: That makes more sense. So my original answer should work....

Comment: @user2731076 I'm beginning to think that `Analyst` refers to something in column S of the individual job number workbooks, but the job number itself is still only in column C of the master workbook - so there is no need to have two loops and the setting of `srcCell = "S" & id : JobNumber = Range(srcCell).Value` is just ... wrong.  But, until the OP clarifies, I am just guessing.  (And they have accepted your answer, so I suspect we may never know.)

Comment: Column C of the master excel has the job numbers which are entered manually. Those are then used in the formula to go through the documents saved in the folder and take the numbers from the cell (TotalN) to the master excel. What I am doing now is in the same documents where i am taking that cell (TotalN), I am taking a new value which is the a name from the cell (Analyst) to go in the "R" column of my master excel. I did make it work with the two for loops, however there might be a more efficient way with the .formula but I am not that familiar with VBA.

Comment: So what is in column S ????  That is the bit we (or, at least, I) are struggling with.

Comment: Column S has the name of the analyst. This is in each sheet in each individual excel document that is created and it changes per sheet per excel as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments that column S does not contain the job number, that column S is simply the column in some other workbook that contains the range name `Analyst`, I believe you want your code to be:

```
Sub Narrative()

    Dim JobNumber As String
    Dim srcCell As String

    Dim id As Long

    For id = 4 To 150
        'Obtain the "job number" from column C of the master sheet
        srcCell = "C" & id
        JobNumber = Range(srcCell).Value
        'Create formulas in column P and R to retrieve values from the 
        'individual job workbooks
        Range("P" & id).Value = "=IFERROR('Y:\Public\QA Other\Scorecards\Scorecard " & JobNumber & ".xlsm'!TotalN, "" "")"
        Range("R" & id).Value = "=IFERROR('Y:\Public\QA Other\Scorecards\Scorecard " & JobNumber & ".xlsm'!Analyst, "" "")"
    Next

End Sub
```

---

If you really want to have two loops (and there really is no need to do so!) then you would still need to get the job number from column C of the master sheet, i.e.

```
Sub Narrative()

    Dim JobNumber As String
    Dim srcCell As String

    Dim id As Long

    For id = 4 To 150
        'Obtain the "job number" from column C of the master sheet
        srcCell = "C" & id
        JobNumber = Range(srcCell).Value
        'Create formula in column P to retrieve value from the 
        'individual job workbooks
        Range("P" & id).Value = "=IFERROR('Y:\Public\QA Other\Scorecards\Scorecard " & JobNumber & ".xlsm'!TotalN, "" "")"
    Next
    For id = 4 To 150
        'Obtain the "job number" from column C of the master sheet
        srcCell = "C" & id
        JobNumber = Range(srcCell).Value
        'Create formula in column R to retrieve value from the 
        'individual job workbooks
        Range("R" & id).Value = "=IFERROR('Y:\Public\QA Other\Scorecards\Scorecard " & JobNumber & ".xlsm'!Analyst, "" "")"
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the JobNumber variable to pull information from a different workbook, you need to qualify which workbook and worksheet you are calling the Range method on. It defaults to the active workbook and worksheet. Try changing your second for loop to:

```
For id = 4 To 150
    srcCell = "S" & id

    JobNumber = Workbooks(wbkName).Worksheets(shtName).Range(srcCell).Value

    Range("R" & id).Value = "=IFERROR('Y:\Public\QA Other\Scorecards\Scorecard " & JobNumber & ".xlsm'!Analyst, "" "")"
Next
```

where wbkName is a string variable with the workbook name (presumably "Scorecard " & JobNumber & ".xlsm") and shtName is a string variable containing the worksheet name in that workbook.

I would suggest creating variables for each workbook/worksheet you are using and qualifying all of your Range methods.

Comment: The problem is that the srcCell is referencing "S" but in the current workbook. I need that source to be the other workbook whose name changes by the variable JobNumber. If I enter that code and fill it in the srcCell, would that work?

Comment: @Josh `srcCell` isn't referencing any workbook - it is simply a `String` such as `"S4"` or `"S5"`.  Only when you use it as the parameter in an unqualified `Range(srcCell)` is it referring to the `ActiveSheet` in the `ActiveWorkbook` (because it defaults to `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(srcCell)`).  If you use `Workbooks(wbkName).Worksheets(shtName).Range(srcCell).Value` then you are referring to a cell (such as cell `"S4"`) in a worksheet whose name is whatever is contained in the `shtName` variable in a (open) workbook whose name is whatever is contained in the `wbkName` variable.

Comment: @user2731076 - `(presumably "Scorecard " & JobNumber & ".xlsm")` - it probably isn't that workbook - it seems unlikely that a list of all "job numbers" would be in a workbook that has a single job number in its filename.  It sounds more likely that there are two control workbooks.  (But I must admit that I am still trying to think up a use case where this situation makes sense.)

Comment: @YowE3K described it perfectly. You are telling Excel which workbook to look in by the name (so long as it is open) and the srcCell string is still just the address of the cell in that workbook. The workbook name can change with JobNumber just like you did in the IFERROR function.